# Android getBaseContext getApplicationContext not working

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse Java developing for Android...

```
Context c = getBaseContext();  // returns null
Context c = this.getBaseContext(); // throws an exception.

Context c = getApplicationContext();  // throws an exception
Context c = this.getApplicationContext();  // throws an exception.

File f = getFilesDir(); // throws an exception
File f = this.getFilesDir(); // throws an exception
```

As you can see I can't get the application or the base context at all.  Trying to get the files dir without them doesn't work.  How on earth can I access my files dir?

```
public class SoundHandler extends Activity {
private Button mButtonPlay;
private Button mButtonDone;
// private LinearLayout mOverallView;
private PeekActivity mHome;
private MyButtonListener myButtonListener;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer; 
private File audioFilePath;

public SoundHandler(PeekActivity home) {
    mHome = home;
    myButtonListener = new MyButtonListener();
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void open() {
    mHome.setContentView(R.layout.sounds);
    mButtonDone = (Button) mHome.findViewById(R.id.soundDone);     
    mButtonDone.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener);
    mButtonPlay = (Button) mHome.findViewById(R.id.playSound);     
    mButtonPlay.setOnClickListener(myButtonListener);
    mPlayer = null;

                // This is what I thought would work, but it does not
    audioFilePath = this.getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();  

                // These are my attempts to see what, if anything works and is not null
                // but I've tried all the combinations and permutations above.
    SoundHandler a = this;
    Context b = getBaseContext();
    Context c = getApplicationContext();
    File d = this.getFilesDir();

                // I'm really just trying to get access to an audio file that is included
                // in my build in file /res/raw/my_audio_file.mp3
                // mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_audio_file); doesn't work either
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can post your code so we get an idea from _where_ you're calling these methods? IIRC `Contexts` should stay `null` until your Activity's superclass' `onCreate()` has been called. Also, you should post the exceptions (with full stack traces) that have been thrown.

Comment: In other words, where are you calling these?

Comment: Are you starting the activity by calling its constructor?

Comment: Does this code answer all these questions?

Answer (score 0):

You are probabably instantiating the Activity or Service, or BroadcastReceiver by yourself. If that is the case, know that these are Android manageable objects, you can't instantiate them, except for Unit Testing. Android System will be responsible to instantiate them based on the Intents that are provided. So don't call their constructors, it might seem to "work" but it will show weird side effects like these ones you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The applicationContext, system services are all initialized after the `setContentView` in the onCreate. It wont work like a java object, since Android defines a Activity as a building block, just like java defines `public static void main` as the starting point. There is less choice here to deviate from the basics.

You need launch a background `Service` and use its context to do all that you need. That way you wont have a front end UI and you can still do all that you need in the background.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this one out.  I had to do it like this.

audioFilePath = mHome.getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

Where "mHome" is the handle (or id or context or whatever you like to call it) for my main overall App Activity.  I.e. It is the parameter passed in to the constructor for this public class.  I.e. if this class was called PlayMyAudio and it's in file PlayMyAudio.java and it is not the main activity of my App.  Then "mHome" is the parameter handed in to my function

public class PlayMyAudio extends Activity {

```
   public PlayMyAudio(AppNameActvity home) {
       mHome = home;
       audioFilePath = mHome.getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();  
   }
```

}